# Unknown custom element Vue Jest Testing on vuetify plugin 2021 - Vue Cli 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

Configuring setup.js inside jest.config.js doesn't solve the error

**setup.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  setupFiles: ["./tests/unit/setup.js"],
};
```

Error Occuring:

- [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<v-app-bar>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
- [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<v-row>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
- [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<v-col>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Setup testing for Vuetify

For vuetify, you will need some changes to make sure everything will work fine.
First of all, create a setup.js file under the project’s tests folder with the following lines:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

After that open package.json file and replace

From

`"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"`

To

`"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile=./tests/setup.js"`

**Let’s write a simple test**

```
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";

describe("example.vue", () => {
   const vuetify = new Vuetify();
   test("False Test", () => {
       const wrapper = mount(Login, {
           stubs: ["router-link", "router-view"],
           vuetify,
    });
    
     const h1 = wrapper.find("h1");
     expect(h1.html()).toBe("<div><p>Foo</p></div>");
  });

  test("True Test", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Login, {
      stubs: ["router-link", "router-view"],
      vuetify,
    });
    const h1 = wrapper.find("h1");
    expect(h1.html()).toBe("<h1>Login</h1>");
  });
```

Comment: You're such a lifesaver !! After hours of research, this only worked. Thank you so much.
Btw, `--setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is depreciated use this inside jest.config instead  `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/plugins/vuetify.ts']`